# SharePoint ignoring crawl rule

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, crawl

I have added this EXCLUDE crawl rule so Allitems.aspx is not shown in search results but it should show the items inside library.

```
http://*/mysite/forms/allitems.aspx
```

When I test this rule by entering the following URL then it says:

**URL**

```
http://myserver/mysite/forms/allitems.aspx
```

**Message**

```
The url will not be crawled because it matches the rule (....my rule here....) marked with a *
```

Which is fine as this is what I want.

But when I search something then it shows this URL in search results. Why is it ignoring this crawl rule even though when I test it, it says it is fine?

Comment: Have you done a full crawl? If that is not enough try resetting the index, and again perform a full crawl

Comment: Yes I have done both several times. In fact I have also cleared browser cache and also restarted IIS several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try excluding contentclass=STS_List_DocumentLibrary.  This should exclude the library but still allow contained documents to come through.

Comment: You mean I should add this "contentclass=STS_List_DocumentLibrary" as a new crawl rule?

Comment: From your original post it looks like you are trying to exclude the library but still get the documents in the library.  I would usually create a scope with this rule rather than restricting at the crawl itself but either should work.